# Contentful Javascript API - looking up an entry by slug

Tags: contentful

I see how to query an Entry by the ID.

Is there a way to lookup by slug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why can't you just do a standard query against the Content Delivery API?

```
/spaces/[space_id]/entries?fields.slug=[my_slug]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm gonna do it! I figured there might be a method that didn't require a query like that, but I also see that the slug field is not necessarily unique so this solution makes more sense.

Comment: Is this method more burdensome than getting the data by directly requesting the id, or does it index the id with the slug parameter? In other words, does it cause a change in the response time of the system? @Deane

Answer (score 25):

If you're using the [SDK](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/sdks/), you might as well do

```
this.contentfulClient.getEntries({
  content_type: 'YOUR_CONTENT_KEY',
  'fields.slug[in]': 'THE_SLUG_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR',
})
```

Comment: this.contentfulClient.getEntries({
  content_type: 'YOUR_CONTENT_KEY',
  'fields.slug[like]': 'THE_SLUG_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR',
})

this is correct?